# Escaping ampersands in JSON for Oracle

Tags: json, oracle, escaping

We are sending JSON to an oracle function and sometimes it contains ampersands. I'd like to know if there is any other way to prevent the "variable substitution" problem because of the ampersand without having to modify the string to

```
'{"this is the JSON &'||' it contains an ampersand"}'
```

I've tried these and they DO NOT WORK.

```
'{"this is the JSON && it contains an ampersand"}'

'{"this is the JSON /& it contains an ampersand"}'

'{"this is the JSON \\& it contains an ampersand"}'
```

**Edit:**

This is how we manually import in Toad:

```
declare
    vOut varchar2(400);
begin
    vOut:=CartJSON.RequestEntry('JSON HERE'); -- function to parse JSON
    dbms_output.put_line('Here:'||vOut);
end;
```

Comment: How are you sending the JSON across to Oracle?

Comment: From PHP to a .Net Webservice that uses Oracle connection to send to Oracle function.

Comment: Usually I believe this only happens when I try to manually import the JSOn using the code in the edited above.

Comment: The use of ampersand as a substitution variable is an Oracle SQL*Plus client feature. So, depends on how you are executing your code and the client. See my answer.

Comment: By "manually" do you mean when you run an insert via Toad / SQLPlus / some other GUI? If so and you're in SQLPLus, then `set define off` or `set define <some other character that isn't used>` before running your statement. If you're in Toad, then there's an option on the right mouse menu to turn substitution variables off. If you're in some other GUI, maybe there's a similar option.

Comment: See comment on Lalit's answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

OP is using TOAD and not SQL*Plus.

---

### TOAD

In TOAD, there are three ways to execute statements without substituting a value for the ampersand(&):

- Menu Level

> View -> TOAD Options: go to the "execute/compile" node/item and
>   uncheck the "Prompt for substitution variables" option.

- Editor Level

> Right click in the editor and uncheck the "Prompt for substitution
>   variables" option.

- Execute as script using set define off

Most of the GUI based tools like SQL Developer, TOAD etc. now support a lot of `SQL*Plus` commands and executing as script seems quite similar to that in `SQL*Plus`. However, it is very much possible that older versions of the GUI tool might not support the `SQL*Plus` commands.

---

### SQL*Plus

The use of **ampersand** as a **substitution variable** is an **Oracle SQL*Plus client** feature.

In `SQL*Plus` you could do

- **SET DEFINE OFF**

For example,

```
SQL> SET DEFINE OFF
SQL> SELECT '{"this is the JSON && it contains an ampersand"}' str FROM dual;

STR
------------------------------------------------
{"this is the JSON && it contains an ampersand"}
```

Or,

- **SET SCAN OFF**

For example,

```
SQL> SET SCAN OFF
SQL> SELECT '{"this is the JSON && it contains an ampersand"}' str FROM dual;

STR
------------------------------------------------
{"this is the JSON && it contains an ampersand"}

SQL>
```

Or,

- Alternatively, you could use **CHR(38)** for the ampersand.

For example,

```
SQL> SELECT '{"this is the JSON '|| chr(38)||chr(38) ||' it contains an ampersand"}' str FROM dual;

STR
------------------------------------------------
{"this is the JSON && it contains an ampersand"}

SQL>
```

Comment: Using `SET DEFINE OFF` or `SET SCAN OFF` gets me a ***Missing or invalid Option*** error on either DEFINE or SCAN

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so now we know you're using Toad, the issue is that you're trying to run the `set define off` as if it's a sql statement (Execute statement at caret / F9) and not as a SQLPlus statement (ie. as part of a script - Execute as script / F5). You have two options:

1: Run both statements as a script (F5):

```
set define off;

declare
    vOut varchar2(400);
begin
    vOut:=CartJSON.RequestEntry('JSON HERE'); -- function to parse JSON
    dbms_output.put_line('Here:'||vOut);
end;
/
```

2. Click with the right mouse button on the editor window and turn off the Substition Variable Prompting, and then run your anonymous block as a single statement (F9).

Comment: I didn't see your answer, it was showing below my answer and the screen was out of the screen. The second option is known to me, although you could do it at menu level too. But the F5 thing to run as a script is just like giving a `SQL*Plus` like feel. I wonder if older versions of the tool would support the `SQL*Plus` commands. That is why I did not mention this option. Usually, `SQL*Plus` commands support varies from version to version of the GUI tool.

Comment: AFAIK, Toad has always supported `set define off` when running scripts. At least, since I've been using it (Toad v7 IIRC).